# Make My Table Responsive

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, media-queries

I have read CSS-Tricks on how to make responsive table, but my table is the other way around.. HORIZONTAL way..
My headings are in the left not at the top of the table. Here's my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6TanY/1/)

```
<table border="1" colspan="1" width="781">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Package</strong>
                </td>
                <td>Silver</td>
                <td>Gold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Number of Books</strong>
                </td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Extra Cover</strong>
                </td>
                <td>Special</td>
                <td>Super Special</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>FREE Pencil</strong>
                </td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So I have two questions about this:

1. How can I make this Responsive? (Not the type that the whole table shrinks, it wont be readable in mobile devices.)
2. Instead of using table, is there an alternative?

Comment: what do you mean with: 'Not the type that the whole table shrinks' ?

Comment: Check css-tricks image http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to contain your table in a div and whenever table overflow just show a scroll bar same with the idea of [**Bootstrap Responsive Tables**](http://jasonbradley.me/bootstrap-responsive-tables/).

You can view a [DEMO HERE](http://cssdesk.com/U3a6Y).

Comment: no, there's a lot to choose from. but this the simplest approach for the problem. and im personally using this since i use twitter bootstrap.

Comment: can you give samples? I mean, like names.. so i can just google them

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the way layers css does tables. - http://eiskis.net/layers/

It's open source so you can download it and check out their method.